# Bash: why kill -STOP a child process makes my child and current process to show the same command line in ps

Tags: linux, bash, child-process, ps, suspend

I have this piece of code in a script. Here is a script called `test.sh` that illustrates it:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
$@ &
pid=$!

#kill -STOP $pid

echo "PID = $pid"
echo '$@  = '"$@"

ps -p $pid -o uname,pid,command
echo
ps -A -o uname,pid,stat,command | grep 'script.sh' | grep -v grep

#kill -CONT $pid
wait $pid

exit 0
```

`kill` commands are commented out, this is intended. What happens is:

- I launch this script with another script as argument: `./test.sh ./script.sh`
- `test.sh` launches `./script.sh`, record its `PID` and shows infos
- Infos show the child PID and a process corresponding to `./script.sh`

```
    root@test# ./test.sh ./script.sh
    PID = 53370
    $@  = ./script.sh
    USER        PID   COMMAND
    root      53370   /bin/bash ./script.sh                  <-- Child process
    
    USER      PID    STAT   COMMAND
    root      53369  S+     /bin/bash ./test.sh ./script.sh  <-- Current process
    root      53370  S+     /bin/bash ./script.sh            <-- Child process
```

Everything normal.

Now, if I uncomment the `kill` commands, the script shows this information:

```
    root@test# ./test.sh ./script.sh
    PID = 53422
    $@  = ./script.sh
    USER        PID   COMMAND
    root      53422   /bin/bash ./test.sh ./script.sh          <-- Child process
    
    USER      PID    STAT   COMMAND
    root      53421  S+     /bin/bash ./test.sh ./script.sh    <-- Current process
    root      53422  T+     /bin/bash ./test.sh ./script.sh    <-- Child process
```

I'm not sure to understand why when I suspend my child process, I get the exact same `COMMAND` value for my *current* process and my *child* process in `ps` output.

Why is this happening? I'd like to understand to mechanism between the parent and the child process in this situation.

Comment: Ok, adding `sleep 0.01` between child process creation and `ps` changed the output and gave me the same result than without suspending the process. So i guess it has nothing to deal with `kill -STOP`, but more with how a process is created? And I was just suspending the child too fast to see its actual command line? The question remains: why do I see the parent's command line? How does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have stopped the child while it was between the `fork()` and the `execve()`, before it was able to execute the `script.sh` script.

Add a `sleep 1` before the `kill -STOP` to see the effect.

A `fork()` creates the child as a *copy* of the parent process (which means that it will show in the `ps` output with the same process name, command line arguments, and almost everything else except the pid). When the child calls the `execve()` system call, it replaces all that.

After a `fork()`, there's no guarantee which of the parent or the child will run first (and in fact, they can run at the same time on separate processors, or any of them could be preempted indefinitely) -- and any "philosophical" conclusions drawn from the order in which they do different operations wrt each other are completely pointless ;-)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know `fork()` had this behavior. I did the `sleep` test, and indeed the `ps` output shows the `COMMAND` value after the `execve()` system call, and it looks like what it should look like in the end. Thank you for explaining